# Using helm to install clusterRole.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm currently using `kubectl create -f clusterRole.yaml` , I was wondering if I can use helm to install it automatically with my chart.

I was looking at the helm documentation, and it used `kubectl create -f` for the clusterRole file. Is there any reason that this can't be done through helm? Is it because this concerns with  access privilege issues?

Comment: If your user could run that `kubectl` command then they can also run `helm install` to create the same object.  The biggest concern is around being able to install the same chart multiple times; you need to make sure the ClusterRole has a name that's globally unique across the entire cluster, not just in the installation namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can install your RBAC roles using your helm chart. As a matter of fact many of the helm charts do configure roles/clusterRoles at install. Here's an example of Elasticsearch [helm chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/templates/role.yaml) which does configure `Role` and `RoleBinding` at install level:

```yaml
{{- if .Values.rbac.create -}}
{{- $fullName := include "elasticsearch.uname" . -}}
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName | quote }}
  labels:
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service | quote }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name | quote }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    app: {{ $fullName | quote }}
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - podsecuritypolicies
    resourceNames:
      {{- if eq .Values.podSecurityPolicy.name "" }}
      - {{ $fullName | quote }}
      {{- else }}
      - {{ .Values.podSecurityPolicy.name | quote }}
      {{- end }}
    verbs:
      - use
{{- end -}}
```

Another example with clusterRole can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/charts/master/stable/kube2iam/templates/clusterrole.yaml).

To sum up, if you context allow you to install desired rbac or any other stuff with `kubectl` then basically you will be able to do so with helm.